# specifying the value change of a Variable value over time not working

Tags: javascript, variables

```
 function destroyer(arr) {

  var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
 arg.splice(0, 1);
  return arr.filter(function (val){
   return arg.indexOf(val) === -1;
  });

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

this code is working accurately. But if replace arg.splice(0, 1) with arg = arg.splice(0, 1); , the code doesn't work. Since arg is a variable so its value can be changed over the course of entire code, why it doesn't work like this? Pardon me if this ques looks silly, but i am new to javascript and very curious in exploring every bit of knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *not* using `arg =` is correct (though you can do it more efficiently, more below). `arg.splice(0, 1)` removes the first element from the original array (changing the array in place), and returns a new array containing only the element that was removed. That is:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.splice(0, 1)); // [1]
console.log(a);              // [2, 3]
```

If you use `arg = arg.splice(0, 1);` you're saying "Remove the first element from `arg` **and** replace the `arg` variable's value with a reference to the new array containing only that removed element. So your subsequent use of `arg` uses the array containing the removed entry, instead of the array you wanted to use.

---

You can and probably should avoid `splice` entirely. Instead, just skip the first argument when copying `arguments`:

```
function destroyer(arr) {

    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // Note --------------------------------------^^^
    return arr.filter(function(val) {
        return arg.indexOf(val) === -1;
    });

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: thanks for providing clarification. but my ques is why it's not working using            'arg=   '

Comment: @RajatChauhan: I told you why: Because `splice` returns a different array, which contains only the removed element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help... i tried the example again & again and now i am ok